# Error-message when using ClusterSEs package, command cluster.im

Tags: r, syntax-error

I have to adjust logistic regression model for cluster standard errors. For this purpose I use the package ClusterSEs and the command cluster.im.

I have to levels in the dataset Tbf2: Individual and village:
Tbf2 is my small dataset consisting of the variable Burned (binary variable; village level), Village (factor, village level) and VoteForER2 (binary, individual level).

My code is provided below:

```
#Make sure the data has the same length,
Tbf1 <- data.frame(cbind(Burned, Village, VoteForER2))
Tbf2 <- na.omit(Tbf1)

#Prediction of support for Authorities on Burned
###ER2 ; logistic regression
fm <- glm(Tbf2$VoteForER2 ~ Tbf2$Burned + Tbf2$, family=binomial(link="logit"))
display(fm)

#Adjusted p-values
clust.p <- cluster.im(fm, Tbf2, Village, ci.level = 0.95, report = T, drop = FALSE)
```

My problem is, that I keep getting the following error-message:

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

And I can't figure out how to solve this. I have two different levels in regression model as far as I can see myself.

I hope somebody will be able to help me!

Best,
Sofie

Answer (score 0):

The *cluster.im* function works the following way:

*Computes p-values and confidence intervals for GLM models based on cluster-specific model estimation
(Ibragimov and Muller 2010). A separate model is estimated in each cluster, and then pvalues
and confidence intervals are computed based on a t/normal distribution of the cluster-specific
estimates.*

Model cannot be estimated for each cluster because the Burned variable for each village is the same for all people - the whole village either burned or not. So the model ask for more data - it says "give me at least 2 different levels of the predictor".